# Detect checkbox checked unchecked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

I'm trying to detect when a checkbox is checked or unchecked in jQuery.
I'm creating the checkboxes dynamically from JSON content. This is how they are created:

```
$.each(data.modifierOptions, function(key, item) {
                            var checkBox = "<input type='checkbox' class='modifier' data-name='" + item.Name + "' + data-price='" + item.Price + "' name='" + item.Name + "' value='" + item.ID + "'/>" + item.Name + "<br/>";
                            $(checkBox).appendTo('#modifiersDiv');
                        });
```

Now, viewing the source of the body I'm getting this:

[image]

Finally, I'm trying to get the checked/unchecked event with this jQuery event, but nothing happens:

```
$('input:checkbox.modifier').change(function () {
            var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
        });
```

How can I solve this?

### Update

I want to get the event by checkbox class.

Comment: use `mousedown()` event listener instead of `change()`.

Comment: This is asked hundred times a week, at least...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .click()

As you are adding a content dynamically you should use,

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox.modifier',  function () {
     var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

Read about delegating events.

Answer (score 1):

Try to code using on event

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox.modifier',  function () {
        var sThisVal = $(this).is(':checked') == true ? $(this).val() : "";
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you create dynamically the checkboxes, you would have to setup the event handler like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox'].modifier", function () {
    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for edit ..Habit of writing jquery selector inside `""` gonna hung me someday..